# Titan Mixed index backed by ES does not have committed data

Tags: indexing, titan

I am loading data in bulk in titan db (v0.5). I have mixed index backed by elasticsearch (v1.2.1). I am loading roughly 400k vertices of same label and can see these in titan db but when I query in ES using mixed index, I do not see those many. I hardly see little over 50k out of those 400k.

While loading I have no error whatsoever coming from ES. This kind of behavior of missing data in ES index, I have noticed randomly with earlier loading too.

I am wondering if someone also has encountered this weird problem. Folks dealing with Titan+ES, do you happen to see this data loss in ES?

Comment: Here are some "sanity check" questions. Are you definitely committing before you query? Also, ES population has an inherent delay. Are you waiting a little bit before querying ES?

Comment: Committing yes, otherwise my post loading audit throw an error. It matches data loaded count from input file and data loaded in database.  But there is no manual delay applied during querying from ES. Do I need to consider this delay aspect? I am fine to put a sec delay( although it will increase loading time)

Comment: Try adding a delay. If it works then I will submit an answer w/ an explanation of why. Cool?

Comment: sure will give it go, will come back tomorrow on this

Comment: @BobB this has worked pretty well. I put a one sec delay. Beside this I also changed library used in connecting Cassandra (this was related to other problem, I was having). I was earlier using thrift and now I am using netflix'x astyanax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, every shard is refreshed automatically once every second. This is why we say that Elasticsearch has near real-time search: document changes are not visible to search immediately, but will become visible within one second.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html